# Export CSV File with Meteor and Iron Router - Loss of Collection Info on the Client

Tags: meteor, export-to-csv, iron-router

I am attempting to export a CSV file from Meteor using Iron-Router on the server side with this code:

```
this.route('export_cand', { // Export Candidates
path: '/export/cand/:_id',
    where: 'server',
    action: function() {
        headers={
            'Content-type': 'text/csv',
    'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename=candidates.csv"
        };
        this.response.writeHead(200, headers);
        strFile='contents of the CSV file';
        this.response.end(strFile);
    }
})
```

The file is successfully generated but the webpage looses all collection information.  Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by loss of collection info? Is the collection empty? Have you published it?

Comment: Yes all the collections are empty, it seems to be only the dev machine that is affected?